# Created view is not visible to user one who is not admin

Tags: views

I created a view. If I login as admin I can see the view when I click on the menu link, but if I login as user [non admin] then I am not able to see it. I have checked the permissions set but normal user can't access the view, only admin.

Note: If I check the box "Bypass content access control" under node on permission setting page than user is able to see, but edit option is also showing up for user and I don't want user to edit the view.

Can anyone tell me why is it? Apart from this view everything else is working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked access permission for that view? And I believe that your views path is not starting with "/admin".

Comment: Please attach screen shot.....@yuvika

Comment: please do check

Comment: Permission is okay. Can you paste views export code here?

Comment: Is it showing access denied when you access the view

Comment: how to export please tell me

Comment: on "admin/structure/views" page there is a last column named operation, beside each view there is option for edit, disable, clone and export. Click on export and paste that code here.

Comment: i cant post its too long i guess need  to mail

Comment: @Vamsi: no its showing view, only admin can able to see my view

Comment: I am asking for non admin users. For non admin users is it showing access denied

Comment: no empty page shows, filter condition they can see but content table grid is not showing

Comment: nilesh.chhatbar1@gmail.com

Comment: Is it throwing error or entire page is blank

Comment: blank , no errors, filter condition are visible

Comment: go to admin/people/permissions and see whether authenticated user has permission to "view published content"

Comment: @vamsi: yes i have checked for required roles,

Comment: not yet recived @yuvika

Comment: Please mention the solution or how did you resolve it, as it will help others if they face the similar issue in future. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a permissions issue.
1. Permission in views edit page under block settings i.e.
   Access:Permission | View published content

2. May be you have set the permissions for the content type / content to authenticated users. Like if you have set the permission that only Authenticated users can view the Basic Page Content, then as an anonymous user you will not be able to view the content or view.

Thanks.

Comment: please tell me where to see?because i have checked here->people->permission->for content type

Comment: just export the view and paste the code here, i will check and let you know the issue.

Comment: how can i export i could not see option, sorry if i am asking dumb question

Comment: Ok np, On the right hand side of Displays you can see a drop down with edit view name/description selected. Just click on arrow and you will be able to see the option / link for Exporting the view.

You can add me on gmail and send me email. My email ID is mohit.1628@gmail.com

Comment: its saying too long so i will post part wise is that fine?

Comment: That's Why I said to Email me :) but part wise will also be fine.

Comment: mohit.1628@gmail.com

Comment: i think its some problem with permission let me check

Comment: Please mention the solution or how did you resolve it, as it will help others if they face the similar issue in future. :)

Comment: I have deleted the view and recreated at the same time menu permission again i reset.it solved the problem